# Cannot resolve method 'getdrawable()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, generator

I'm a newbie in programming. I want to build a QR Code Generator that the QR Code can be saved or downloaded.

Here's my code for the generator:

```
    public class GeneratorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText text;
    Button gen_btn;
    ImageView image;
    String text2Qr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_generator);
        text = findViewById(R.id.text);
        gen_btn = findViewById(R.id.gen_btn);
        image = findViewById(R.id.image);
        gen_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text2Qr = text.getText().toString().trim();
                MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
                try{
                    BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text2Qr, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200);
                    BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                    Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ImageView.getdrawable()).getBitmap();

                }
                catch (WriterException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
    }
}
```

I got a error that I cannot resolve method 'getdrawable()

anybody know how to fix this?

Here's the screenshot of the error: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSwMq.jpg)

Comment: hi please include error screenshot or the text of error thanks

Comment: @Gulz okay let me try

Comment: Pay close attention to the variable name, and capitalization in the method name. It should be exactly `image.getDrawable()`. Furthermore, you should listen to [theanilpaudel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48616494), because what you're doing on that line is pointless. You already have `bitmap`.

Comment: looks like you are missing Java basics. Please take some time to learn what is a class, an object, static and non-static methods. Or you will get 1000 more problems like this.

Comment: I'm really sorry guys. I still can't save it or download the Image from the app. I know I need to learn more, but my situation right now is I really need this thing works for my project and I just tried like yesterday. My deadline is near. Sorry for making a trouble in this site. I guess my idiot post will never be touch again

Answer (score 1):

[**`getDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

> Return a drawable object associated with a particular resource ID and
>   styled for the specified theme.

You should pass **`OBJECT`**

```
bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

FYI

```
Drawable drawable = image.getDrawable();
```

Comment: @ricardoseikka Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Comment: I'm sorry Sir, if you put a link that I need to read that makes me more confused. I'm still newbie, I'm so sorry

Comment: what should I look into that question? the most vote one? I tried the code he post too. I can't resolve the symbol 'imview' and 'GlideBitmapDrawable'

Comment: I still got the issue sir, and refer to that question that you just post, the most voted answer is in the code that I already tried. And I just tried it again and still nothing works. So please help me sir

Comment: @ricardoseikka Kindly check updated answer. Let me inform.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you sir for the correction. Indeed i'm still way to go to learn this thing. I tried it and already build the apk but there's nothing changes from it. I still can't download or save the Image from the generator.

Answer (score 1):

get the drawable like from imageview like

```
Drawable myDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
```

You can compare it with a drawable resource like

```
if(iv.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)){
    //do work here
}
```

Comment: I tried the Drawable myDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
didn't work too :(

Comment: can u please here `imageView` is your `image` did u try with `image.getDrawable(); ` ?

Comment: I did just like IntelliJ Amiya answer. But still didn't work

Comment: try like this`imageView.buildDrawingCache(); Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();` . and let me know if it works

Comment: builddrawingcache and getdrawingcache is cannot resolve :(

Comment: can u please show me code how are you doing. paste code of `onClick` here paste.ofcode.org

Comment: Its the same on the top though

Comment: Okay, I'll be waiting

Comment: please check now, i have updated code. check here https://paste.ofcode.org/Yu9tj4FDqSqFesV6bJPDM4

Comment: if not work. i will give you another updated code. Let me know

Comment: already build the apk, still can't save or download the image from generator.

Comment: i did not get you. if u want to save bitmap that is set on `ImageView` then u already have bitmap, why not u using that bitmap ?

Comment: When the app is running, I tried to click on the image to save it or tried to download it. But nothing shows. The Image just stay in the app that I generate

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new in this. I don't really know how to do it properly

Comment: okay, can u check in log or do if else to check `bitMatrix` is null or not

Comment: how to check the bitmatrix? I'm really sorry for stupid question

Comment: `if(bitmatrix!=null){ Log.d("bitmatrix","is not null");}else{Log.d("bitmatrix","is null. please check. bitmatrix again");}

Comment: can you post it on here again sir how the bitmatrix do? paste.ofcode.org

Comment: here is updated code with null checking https://paste.ofcode.org/rbgsrGYuhk8ssHyfLx9ygF

Comment: Okay, it said the argument 'bitmatrix' might be null

Comment: can u please check log. what log showing? either Log text present in  if or else print when u onClick called

Comment: Error:(50, 28) error: variable bitmap is already defined in method onClick(View)

Comment: this error must not come. please come on chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158290/room-for-ashu-kumar-and-ramona

Comment: my reputation is not enough to talk on there

Comment: yeah, can u please tell me about log what it displaying and where is error, Please show me ur updated code

Comment: on where can I check the actual log that you mention?

Comment: in logcat @ricardoseikka u can check

Comment: already did just now on sdk, sorry for late respond. I took so long for the sdk to run, and the generator won't shows. on it

Comment: and i got scanner on that app too so only the scanner is shows up, the logcat just fill with so many emulatedcamera

Comment: try searching by class name as i loged values with class name `GeneratorActivity`

Comment: I can't find the GeneratorActivity class in the logcat

Comment: error is till there? , try searching `bitMatrix` in log cat

Comment: can't find the bitmatrix too

Comment: please do project clean.  and run your project again. and check log after pressing button

Comment: somehow the logcat won't clean even after i click on 'clean project' and 'clean logcat'

Comment: okay, cleaning log cat will not clean log cat as data will display from mobile or emulator activity happening in it. i will be back in 30 min

Comment: your rep is 22. now u can able chat. let me know when u r ready. @ricardoseikka

Comment: wait, my android-studio is stop working. I will restart it first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164536/discussion-between-ashu-kumar-and-ricardo-seikka). @ricardoseikka

Answer (score 0):

You already have a bitmap and you have set it to imageview. Why do you need this line

> bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ImageView.getdrawable()).getBitmap();

The error is saying that there is no method called getDrawable() in the ImageView class.

Comment: I need to make the qr code that i generate is downloadable or can be save to gallery phone. I'm sorry i think thats the code to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it `Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);`directly. may be not need `bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getdrawable()).getBitmap();`

Comment: It can't make the QR Code Image save in gallery :(

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `drawable` from empty `imageview` that will return null. for getting bitmap from `drawble`, try this method.

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help you!!